# css background color only of text justify

Tags: css, background-color, text-justify

I want to set the background color only of a justified text
(like when the text is selected by the mouse)

I've tried with `div`,

or `span` inside `div`,

or `p` without `margin`,

or `h1` display inline,

but no one of these solutions solved my problem.

I **don't** mean the `::selection` pseudo, but the text background that is always displayed

I want exactly this:

[image]

Please help

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tsXuH/)**

Comment: Strange. `<span>` inside `<div>` did it for me? See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tsXuH/14/)

HTML

```
<div class="CC ">
    <div class="bg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bg {
    background-color:red;
    display:inline;
    padding: 1px 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `background` property to whatever color you'd like.

[Updated JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/tsXuH/3/)

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tsXuH/11/)**

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="CC ">
        <div class="bg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.bg {
    background-color:red;
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: I've tried your code under chrome and firefox, but there are grey lines between rows...

Comment: just add line-height on the .CC to fix this: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/tsXuH/13/

Answer (score 0):

The desired appearance requires the use of an inline element, since that is the way to stop the background where the text ends. Since you also want justified text, which requires a block element, you need two elements: a `span`, containing all the text of the block, nested inside a `div` or `p`:

```
<div class="CC"><span class="CCC">Lorem ipsum ... in futurum.</span></div>
```

The you just set the background on the `span` element:

```
.CCC { background: red; color: yellow }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can give like this

```
::selection {
    background: #ffb7b7; /* Safari */
    }
::-moz-selection {
    background: #ffb7b7; /* Firefox */
}
```

or

```
p::selection {
    background: #ffb7b7; /* Safari */
    }
```